# Error Propagation in calculating Binary logarithm by hand

Tags: logarithms, binary, elementary-functions, error-propagation

I am interested in the idea of arithmetic performed in binary done without electronics. In particular, I’d like to try calculating the binary logarithm of x (where 10 > x >= 1) using the square/division algorithm wherein I square the mantissa, write a 0 if the result is less than 10, else write a 1 and divide the mantissa by 10.

(The above numbers are in binary. The subscript I tried to use for indicating the base looked awful.)

The problem is the bit length for intermediate values. If I want to find the binary log to sixteen or twenty bits, my working value will have a bit length in the millions of bits.

What I would like to know specifically is how much and how often I can truncate the intermediate values without losing accuracy for the sixteen significant bits and for n significant bits in general. I figure that I need four or five extra bits for each position of the approximation, but I’d like to be sure.

EDIT: In other words, if I did all the work with the millions of bits, exactly how much effort would I be wasting? Is there a general rule that allows me to truncate each intermediate mantissa after m bits without making any difference to the first n bits of the log, and if so, what is the relationship between m and n?

EDIT: Question reworded to be more clear. I apologize.

Comment: This is a great way to get experience with numerical computation!Try using an increasing list of bit lengths and see what happens. Then tell us what results you found.

Answer (score 0):

**Can I truncate the intermediate values without losing absolute accuracy?**

Short answer: **no**.

Not so short answer: Regarding add (and substraction) *absolute* errors sum up, for multiplication (also dividing) *relative* errors sum up. While only interested in a result of 20 bits you may calculate what truncation is possible without harm.

$2^{20}\approx 10^6$, thus six or better seven *decimal* digits of accurancy should be ok.

Comment: “ While only interested in a result of 20 digits (or bits in your case), you may calculate what truncation is possible without harm.”
This is what I was after. What is the calculation for n bits in general? If I want 14 decimal digits of accuracy, do I need only 15-17 digits in my intermediate values? If I want 28, do my intermediate values need 29-31?

Comment: @MMLgamer -- For 20 bits the calculation is $2^{20}=10^x$ then take $\lceil x \rceil$. For 14 _decimal digits_ you must know how many bits (and therefore how many square/division operations) you need for that.

Comment: Sorry, I only mentioned decimal digits because your answer was put in terms of decimal digits. If I keep it strictly binary and image a worst case scenario where I square and divide on every step, does that mean for n bits, I must leave 2n bits plus maybe a guard bit after the truncation?

Comment: @MMLgamer -- Your _"binary logarithm of x (where 2 > x >= 1)"_, that  $x$ is binary or decimal? If decimal then IMO the wording is "decimal digits", if binary I may say bits instead. Me think.

Comment: Again sorry. I used the term “2” to keep it simple. I’ll edit my question to be more clear.